# findViewbyId undefined for the type mainactivity

Tags: android

I get that error on my Button line but I do have button defined with that ID.  Please help.  Thx.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button calc = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.btnCalc);
```

Comment: post your full code along with `activity_main.xml`

Comment: and please clarify your problem statement.  Is this a compile failure or is the runtime call returning null?

Comment: Did you define the button id inside activity_main.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call the method correctly. Remember it is case sensitive.

```
Button Calc = (Button) findViewbyId(R.id.btnCalc)
```

should be

```
Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalc)
```

Note the capital B in By.

If you use eclipse then CTRL + space gives code assist and autocompletion. That should help those mistakes in future.

Answer (score -1):

check your Gen folder-> R class-> btnCalc is autocreated or not.
if not: may be chances of error in XML file.

In eclipse -> Project-> Clean the project.